# fail to access child iframe content as expected

Tags: dom, iframe, same-origin-policy

Just try a very simple case about **<iframe>** tag usage, while the result confused me. Hope anyone can help me. I am waitting, thanks.

Basically, I have two simple pages, **top.html** and **iframe.html**, they are the same domain, and **iframe.html** is the **"src"** of **<iframe>** tag in **top.html**.

When I try to access **<iframe>** content in **top.html**, while result is so wierd, all elements are blank.

console log from **top.html** is so wierd, and console log from **iframe.html** is expected.

***// console log from top.html after load page***

```
outer log: NodeList[head, body]  ---  top.html (line 6)
outer log: 2                     ---  top.html (line 7)
outer log: ""                    ---  top.html (line 8)
```

***// console log from ifram.html after click button in***

```
inner log: NodeList[head, <TextNode textContent="\n">, body]  ---  iframe.html (line 6)
inner log: 3                                                  ---  iframe.html (line 7)
inner log: "Child iFrame"                                     ---  iframe.html (line 8)
```

***// top.html***

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="fid" src="/iframe.html"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var i = document.getElementById("fid");
  console.log("outer log: %o", i.contentDocument.documentElement.childNodes);
  console.log("outer log: %o", i.contentDocument.documentElement.childNodes.length);
  console.log("outer log: %o", i.contentDocument.documentElement.childNodes[1].innerHTML);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***// iframe.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show () {
  var x = window.top.document.getElementById("fid");
  console.log("inner log: %o", x.contentDocument.documentElement.childNodes);
  console.log("inner log: %o", x.contentDocument.documentElement.childNodes.length);
  console.log("inner log: %o", x.contentDocument.documentElement.childNodes[2].childNodes[1].innerHTML);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Child iFrame</p>
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="Show Button" />
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: _“result is so wierd, all elements are blank”_ – that’s probably just because you did not wait for the iframe content to be fully loaded …

Comment: Thanks CBroe, sigh... so shame, I was stuck in it for several minutes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add testing into window.onload, result is as expected.